# Comparison of dates showing unexpected results?

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

A really simple question. Are these two dates different:

`2020-09-02T00:00:00.000+00:00` and `2020-09-02T15:39:00+04:00`

I mean if I compare them will I get true or false.
The date I am retrieving from the backend (MongoDB) is `2020-09-02T00:00:00.000+00:00` and the one I am passing in the request body is `2020-09-02T15:39:00+04:00`. The result I am getting is false when comparing.

If they are not the same, how do I convert this date `2020-09-02T15:39:00+04:00` into the DB format. I only want the dates to be checked not the time. TIA

Comment: something like  ` moment("2017-10-09T00:00:00Z").isSameOrAfter(moment("2017-10-09 22:00:00+00:00").utc().startOf('day'), 'day');`   timezones matter even if u want to compare just the date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse the strings to `Date` objects and then compare the dateStrings.
[toDateString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString) returns the date portion of a `Date`object as a readable string.

```
const date1 = new Date("2020-09-02T00:00:00.000+00:00");
const date2 = new Date("2020-09-02T15:39:00+04:00");

function compareDates(date1, date2) {
  return date1.toDateString() === date2.toDateString();
}

compareDates(date1, date2); //true
```

But since you're handling different timezones I would suggest to use other methods.

```
const date1 = new Date("2020-09-02T00:00:00.000+00:00");
const date2 = new Date("2020-09-02T15:39:00+04:00");

function compareDates(date1, date2) {
  return date1.getUTCFullYear() === date2.getUTCFullYear() &&
         date1.getUTCMonth() === date2.getUTCMonth() &&
         date1.getUTCDate() === date2.getUTCDate();
}

compareDates(date1, date2); //true
```

the `getUTC...` methods return the year, month or day according to universal time.

Comment: I dont want to check the timezones just the date so will the first method you suggested be enough for that?